# Scrolling the child items inside parent items in Expandable list

Tags: java, android, android-studio, expandablelistview

I have used expandable list in my project . Can I scroll the child items inside expandable list I mean I have very long list of child items inside one parent item of Expandable List item , so can I scroll it as per my use.